# how to set max_write_buffer_size in BaseIOStream class object in tornado?

Tags: tornado

In tornado webserver code, SSLIOStream inherits from IOStream and that inherits BaseIOStream class.
BaseIOStream has max_write_buffer_size from where we start the tornado server. I did not find any usage of environment variable to set, it has to be passed as constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

From the [source code](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/iostream.html#BaseIOStream) someone can observe that `max_write_buffer_size` is not a private variable. Therefore you have access on it either from a `BaseIOStream` object or from any object of the classes `SSLIOStream` and `IOStream` which inherits from the `BaseIOStream`.

So for example:

```
import socket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.iostream
import tornado.options

# def connect_baseiostream():
#    sock = socket.socket()
#    stream = tornado.iostream.BaseIOStream(sock)
#    stream.max_write_buffer_size = 10000 # Set max_write_buffer_size

def connect_iostream():
    sock = socket.socket()
    stream = tornado.iostream.IOStream(sock)
    stream.max_write_buffer_size = 10000 # Set max_write_buffer_size
    stream.connect(host, port) # Defined host and port

def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(connect_iostream)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This parameter is not exposed in HTTP servers, because the use is limited and probably default value is the right one (unlimited). Of course you may create an issue for that and discuss it on [github](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado). The other solution is to subclass [`tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html#http-server) with own implementation of [`TCPServer's handle_connection`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/tcpserver.py#L257) (keep in mind it is private `_` method).

```
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer

max_write_buffer_size = 65535

class CustomHTTPServer(HTTPServer):

    def _handle_connection(self, connection, address):
    # https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/tcpserver.py#L257
           if self.ssl_options is not None:
               assert ssl, "Python 2.6+ and OpenSSL required for SSL"
               try:
                   connection = ssl_wrap_socket(connection,
                                                self.ssl_options,
                                                server_side=True,
                                                do_handshake_on_connect=False)
               except ssl.SSLError as err:
                   if err.args[0] == ssl.SSL_ERROR_EOF:
                       return connection.close()
                   else:
                       raise
               except socket.error as err:
                   if errno_from_exception(err) in (errno.ECONNABORTED, errno.EINVAL):
                       return connection.close()
                   else:
                       raise
           try:
               if self.ssl_options is not None:
                   stream = SSLIOStream(connection, io_loop=self.io_loop,
                                        max_buffer_size=self.max_buffer_size,
                                        read_chunk_size=self.read_chunk_size,
                                        max_write_buffer_size=max_write_buffer_size)
               else:
                   stream = IOStream(connection, io_loop=self.io_loop,
                                     max_buffer_size=self.max_buffer_size,
                                     read_chunk_size=self.read_chunk_size,
                                     max_write_buffer_size=max_write_buffer_size)

               future = self.handle_stream(stream, address)
               if future is not None:
                   self.io_loop.add_future(gen.convert_yielded(future),
                                           lambda f: f.result())
           except Exception:
               app_log.error("Error in connection callback", exc_info=True)
```

And use customized server:

```
    application = web.Application([
        (r"/", MainPageHandler),
    ])
    http_server = CustomHTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8080)
    ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```